# Merging the keys of two dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

What is the best way to merge only the keys of two dictionaries?

For example we have:

```
private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _dictionary1= new Dictionary<string, string>{{"1","one"},{"2","two"}};
private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _dictionary2 = new Dictionary<string, string>(){{"3","three"}};
```

What I want to receive is the list containing {"1","2","3"}.

Comment: In a specific order? Duplicates removed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx

Comment: @Thilo, no specific order, the duplicates should be removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine to `Key` arrays:

```
var a = _dictionary1.Keys.Union(_dictionary2.Keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

UNIQUE keys using [Enumerable.Union()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method:

```
  var mergedKeys = _dictionary1.Keys.Union(_dictionary2.Keys);
```

ALL keys using [Enumerable.Concat()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) method:

```
var mergedKeys = _dictionary1.Keys.Concat(_dictionary2.Keys);
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) and [`Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.union.aspx) methods.